# Changing particular text to Times New Roman

Tags: fonts

I am trying to recreate the Maple UI in a LaTeX document. Therefore I need certain text in my document to be in Times New Roman and I want the rest of the text in my document to remain as the default font. Any ideas as to how to do this?

Comment: Probably `xelatex` and fontspec` is the simplest way to do that.

Comment: Hm: Off-topic: Times New Roman is an ugly font ;-)

Comment: Have you read [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document) ?